# C++ dynamic_cast behavior when cast fails

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

`dynamic_cast` evaluates to `NULL` if the cast involves pointers, but throws a `bad_cast` exception if the cast involves reference types.

Why this difference in behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no such thing as NULL reference :)

Comment: Actually there could be null reference!

Comment: This code will compile, but will result in undefined behavior: `int &i = *((int *)0);`. It would be wrong for `dyanmic_cast` to result in undefined behavior in the (not rare) case an invalid type was chosen as the endpoint of a cast, so it throws an exception instead, which is well-defined behavior. :-)

Comment: Yeah, i was looking for more of a high level reason here, James Kanze pretty much summed it up, you can't initialize a reference without an object for it to refer to.

Comment: @Omnifarious: That is my thought :D

Comment: Also note that there's no reference analogue of `dynamic_cast<void*>`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes. :-) I found your phrasing awkward and difficult to understand. I should've credited you with the original thought.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there could be null reference (or rather reference to null), but it is undefined behavior (UB). Since the Standard doesn't *define* UB, so `dynamic_cast` throws exception which is pretty much well-defined.

Comment: Im not following :) Explain please :)

Comment: A reference to NULL would have the type `int const&`, but I don't think that this is what you mean.  You cannot initialize a reference without a valid object for it to refer to, however.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That is what I mean.